# List traversal with two adjacent elements in a Functional way

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm trying to implement functional version of the below code

```
 const adjacent = (list)  => {
    let results = [];
    for (let idx = 0; idx < list.length - 1; idx++) {
      const computedRes = someComplexFn(list[idx], list[idx + 1]);
      results.push(computedRes );
    }
    return results;
  }
```

i have come with the following version

```
const locations = [1,2,3,4,5];
const calcRatioFn = (x, y) => x+y;

const adjacentMap = (list, result=[]) => {
  if(R.length(list) < 2) {
    return result;
  }
  const f1 = R.head(list);
  const f2 = R.tail(list);
  result.push(calcRatioFn(f1 ,R.head(f2)));

  return adjacentMap(R.tail(list), result);
}


const results = adjacentMap(locations);
console.log(results);
```

Are any any other simple solution to the above?

Can we avoid the default result value parameter and if condition check from the above function?

JSBin Link
http://jsbin.com/veyihepulu/1/edit?html,js,console

Comment: A typical solution is to use `drop` + `zip`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to create a sliding window of adjacent elements using [`R.aperture`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#aperture). Then for a bit of extra sugar `someComplexFn` can be wrapped with [`R.apply`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#apply) to convert the binary function into one that accepts an array of two elements.

Your example would then look something like:

```
const adjacentMap = R.pipe(R.aperture(2), (R.map(R.apply(someComplexFn))))
```

Comment: thanks elegant solution. how about 0 or 1 element edge case?

Comment: @vito Passing in a list with 0 or 1 elements will result in an empty list. Did you have a different result in mind?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use `converge` on the array without the last element and the array without the first element.

```
let locations = [1,2,3,4,5];
const calcRatio = (x, y) => x+y;

// adjacentMap :: Array -> Array
const adjacentMap = R.converge(
    R.zipWith(calcRatio), 
    [ R.init, R.tail]
);

// saveAdjacentMap :: Array -> Array
const saveAdjacentMap = R.cond([
    [R.compose(R.lt(1), R.length), adjacentMap ],
    [R.T, R.identity]
]);

console.log(saveAdjacentMap(locations));
```

Your JSBin uses Ramda 0.8.0. Things have changed in the current version `0.24.1`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code maybe what you require or can be adapted for your required solution.

```
const fn = (acc, c, i, a) => {
  return !(a[i + 1]) 
    ? acc
    : acc.concat(c + a[i + 1])
}

const _adjacentMap = (fn, list) => {
  return list.reduce(fn, [])
}

const locations = [1,2,3,4,5]

const result = _adjacentMap(fn, locations)

console.log(result)
// => [ 3, 5, 7, 9 ]
```